# Attaching a file using linklabel in winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a link label and tried to attach multiple no. of files. But when I'm clicking OK it was not attaching the files.  I also attached the picture. Can you please let me know where is the mistake

```
private void Attach_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string filePath in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                    Attach.Text += fileName + Environment.NewLine;

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "attach"?  Where is it supposed to "attach" to?

Comment: And I don't think you're showing all the relevant code.  For instance, you have `Attach.Text` but where is `Attach` coming from?

Comment: attach is the name of the linklabel.  I understanded until ''string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);" but after that I cannot proceed how to move further

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the event correctly. Don't try to link to the FileOK event of the openFileDialog... instead, use the result of the modal window to perform your actions:

```
    private void Attach_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
             foreach (string filePath in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
             {
                  if (File.Exists(filePath))
                  {
                       string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                       Attach.Text += fileName + Environment.NewLine;
                   }
              }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A Link Label will not help to attach a file. If you just want to display the name of the files that you have selected change your code to this:

```
Attach.Text = string.Empty;
foreach (string filePath in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                    Attach.Text += fileName + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
```

Also, make sure to set the property "Multiselect" of openFileDialog1 to true.